# Combinatorics in excel: Find every possible sum of every possible combination

Tags: vba, excel, math, discrete-mathematics

Ok, I´ve found similar questions but none of them solve this problem so here I go:

I´ve a list of individuals (col. "A"), and each of them has a value assigned for a determined parameter (col. "B").
I´ve some target parameter values and I want to know which combinations of individuals sum up "x" for that parameter value.

Let´s take an example:

```
      Col. A                      Col. B

       M                            10
       N                           -5
       O                           -8
       P                            0.87
       Q                            9

     - Target for Parameter("X"): 9-10

     - Solution:
                S1= Q+P -> 9.87
                S2= Q   -> 9
```

As you can see just by inspection, the only ways to do this is taking Q, or Q+P.
But in my case, I´ve between 10-15 subjects each time, and doing the work by inspection is not easy at all.

I would want to generate a chart with all the possible values (being able to know which subjects are generating the value), or just a way to know the "y" closest combinations.

Comment: It's not a VBA solution, and so is not particularly efficient, though if you're interested then perhaps you can adapt the set-up I give here to meet your needs: http://excelxor.com/2014/08/26/which-numbers-add-up-to-total/

Comment: Thanks XOR, it´s not VBA but seems useful anyway!

Comment: Could you provide a few more examples. All I need is column B min/max/average/count and the target min and max. Examples should ideally have high counts, high target mins and low target range (absolute target min/max difference).

Answer (score 2):

The original question involved 5 values for which a brute force approach was acceptable.  The number of values was then increased and more sophisticated approaches were required.  I suggest you start with this answer, which describes the brute force approach, followed by:

- [Approach 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26653009/973283)
- [Approach 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911006/973283)
- [Approach 3, code part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926953/973283)
- [Approach 3, code part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926988/973283)

**First answer**

You need to break your requirement into a number of simple steps. It may be possible to combine two or more steps but complex steps take more time to write and more time to debug.  Start simple.  Once your code is working, you can worry about making faster or prettier or whatever is necessary.  Too many programmers forget that fast, pretty code that does not work is useless.

I created a worksheet “Source” and populated it with values so:

[image: Source.png]

I need to put the minimum and maximum values somewhere so I placed them on this worksheet.

I created a worksheet “Result”.  The output from the macro below is:

[image: Result.png]

You do not list “10  M” as a solution.  I do not know if this is an oversight or if your interpretation of range “9-10” is different from mine.  Change the line `If ValueMin <= ValueCrnt And ValueMax >= ValueCrnt Then` if necessary.

I notice that my columns are not in the same sequence as yours.  This is an easy change which I leave for you as an exercise.

There are three major steps in my solution.

**Step 1**

On my worksheet the relevant data is on rows 2 to 6.  You indicate you will want to add further values.  The start row is fixed so I have defined it using a constant:

```
Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2
```

The value of `RowSrcDataLast`, the last row containing data, is determined by code.

**Step 2**

Although your objective is to process keys and values, you are interested in rows at this stage.  For example:

- Is the value on row 2 within the required range?
- Is the sum of the values on rows 2 and 3 within the required range?
- Is the sum of the values on rows 2, 4 and 6 within the required range?

If the answer to any of these questions is “Yes”, then create an expression from the keys.

You need the row numbers to get at the keys and values.

My macro fills the array `SrcRows` with the values 2 to `RowSrcDataLast`.  It then calls a subroutine `GenerateCombinations`.     I use variations of this subroutine for any problem of this type.

`GenerateCombinations` takes two arrays as parameters, `Value` and `Result`, plus a separator characters.  On return, `Result` returns an array containing a concatenated string for every combination of the values in Value.  If Value contains the values: 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, the returned strings are:

```
Inx Combination
  0  
  1  2
  2  3
  3  2|3
  4  4
  5  2|4
  6  3|4
  7  2|3|4
  8  5
  9  2|5
 10  3|5
 11  2|3|5
 12  4|5
 13  2|4|5
 14  3|4|5
 15  2|3|4|5
 16  6
 17  2|6
 18  3|6
 19  2|3|6
 20  4|6
 21  2|4|6
 22  3|4|6
 23  2|3|4|6
 24  5|6
 25  2|5|6
 26  3|5|6
 27  2|3|5|6
 28  4|5|6
 29  2|4|5|6
 30  3|4|5|6
 31  2|3|4|5|6
```

I think there are enough comments within the routine to explain how it generates this result.

**Step 3**

The macro loops down the returned array, splitting the returned string and accessing each row of that combination.

I hope that all makes sense.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can decipher my code by yourself, the faster you will understand it.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Control()

  ' Using constants instead of literals has the following effects:
  '  1) It takes longer to type the code.  For example:
  '       ValueMin = .Range(CellSrcMin).Value    takes longer to type than
  '       ValueMin = .Range("C3").Value
  '  2) The code is self-documenting.  The purpose of ".Range(CellSrcMin).Value"
  '     is a lot more obvious than the purpose of ".Range("C3").Value".  This may
  '     not matter today but, when you return to this macro in 6 months, self-
  '     documenting code is a real help.
  '  3) If a cell address, a column code or a worksheet name changes, all you
  '     have to do is change the value of the constant and the code is fixed.
  '     Scanning you code for every occurance of a literal and deciding if it
  '     one that needs to change is a nightmare.

  Const CellSrcMin As String = "C3"
  Const CellSrcMax As String = "D3"
  Const ColRsltValue As String = "A"
  Const ColRsltKeyExpn As String = "B"
  Const ColSrcKey As String = "A"
  Const ColSrcValue As String = "B"
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2
  Const WshtNameRslt As String = "Result"
  Const WshtNameSrc As String = "Source"

  Dim InxResultCrnt As Long
  Dim InxResultPartCrnt As Long
  Dim InxSrcRowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowRsltCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcDataLast As Long
  Dim SrcRows() As String
  Dim Result() As String
  Dim ResultPart() As String
  Dim ValueCrnt As Double
  Dim ValueKey As String
  Dim ValueMin As Double
  Dim ValueMax As Double

  ' Find last row containing data
  With Worksheets(WshtNameSrc)
    RowSrcDataLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcKey).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  ' Rows RowSrcDataFirst to RowSrcDataLast contain data.
  ' Size SrcRows so it can hold each value in this range
  ReDim SrcRows(1 To RowSrcDataLast - RowSrcDataFirst + 1)

  ' Fill SrcRows with every row that contains data
  RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst
  For InxSrcRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(SrcRows)
    SrcRows(InxSrcRowCrnt) = RowSrcCrnt
    RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
  Next

  ' Generate every possible combination
  Call GenerateCombinations(SrcRows, Result, "|")

  ' Output contents of Result to Immediate Window.
  ' Delete or comment out once you fully understand what
  ' GenerateCombinations is doing.
  Debug.Print "Inx Combination"
  For InxResultCrnt = 0 To UBound(Result)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxResultCrnt, 3) & "  " & Result(InxResultCrnt)
  Next

  ' Get the minimum and maximum values
  With Worksheets(WshtNameSrc)
    ValueMin = .Range(CellSrcMin).Value
    ValueMax = .Range(CellSrcMax).Value
  End With

  ' Initialise result worksheet
  With Worksheets(WshtNameRslt)
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    With .Range("A1")
      .Value = "Total"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    .Range("B1").Value = "Key Expn"
    .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    ' This value will be overwritten if any combination gives an acceptable value
    .Range("A2").Value = "No combination gives a value in the range " & _
                         ValueMin & " to " & ValueMax
  End With
  RowRsltCrnt = 2

  With Worksheets(WshtNameSrc)

    ' Get the minimum and maximum values
    ValueMin = .Range(CellSrcMin).Value
    ValueMax = .Range(CellSrcMax).Value

    ' For each result except first which is no row selected
    For InxResultCrnt = 1 To UBound(Result)
      ResultPart = Split(Result(InxResultCrnt), "|")
      ValueCrnt = 0#
      For InxResultPartCrnt = 0 To UBound(ResultPart)
        ValueCrnt = ValueCrnt + .Cells(ResultPart(InxResultPartCrnt), ColSrcValue).Value
      Next
      If ValueMin <= ValueCrnt And ValueMax >= ValueCrnt Then
        ' This value within acceptable range
        Worksheets(WshtNameRslt).Cells(RowRsltCrnt, ColRsltValue) = ValueCrnt
        ' Create key string
        ValueKey = .Cells(ResultPart(0), ColSrcKey).Value
        For InxResultPartCrnt = 1 To UBound(ResultPart)
          ValueKey = ValueKey & "+" & .Cells(ResultPart(InxResultPartCrnt), ColSrcKey).Value
        Next
        Worksheets(WshtNameRslt).Cells(RowRsltCrnt, ColRsltKeyExpn) = ValueKey
        RowRsltCrnt = RowRsltCrnt + 1
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
Sub GenerateCombinations(ByRef Value() As String, ByRef Result() As String, _
                         ByVal Sep As String)

  ' * On entry, array Value contains values.  For example: A, B, C.
  ' * On exit, array Result contains one entry for every possible combination
  '   of values from Value.  For example, if Sep = "|":
  '     0)             ' None of the values is an allowable combination
  '     1)  A
  '     2)  B
  '     3)  A|B
  '     4)  C
  '     5)  A|C
  '     6)  B|C
  '     7)  A|B|C
  ' * The bounds of Value can be any valid range,
  ' * The lower bound of Result will be zero.  The upper bound of Result
  '   will be as required to hold all combinations.

  Dim InxRMax As Integer        ' Maximum used entry in array Result
  Dim InxVRCrnt As Integer      ' Working index into arrays Value and InxResultCrnt
  Dim NumValues As Long         ' Number of values
  Dim InxResultCrnt() As Long   ' Entry = 1 if corresponding value
                                ' selected for this combination

  NumValues = UBound(Value) - LBound(Value) + 1

  ReDim Result(0 To 2 ^ NumValues - 1)                 ' One entry per combination
  ReDim InxResultCrnt(LBound(Value) To UBound(Value))  ' One entry per value

  ' Initialise InxResultCrnt for no values selected
  For InxVRCrnt = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
    InxResultCrnt(InxVRCrnt) = 0
  Next

  InxRMax = -1
  Do While True
    ' Output current result
    InxRMax = InxRMax + 1
    If InxRMax > UBound(Result) Then
      ' There are no more combinations to output
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Result(InxRMax) = ""
    For InxVRCrnt = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
      If InxResultCrnt(InxVRCrnt) = 1 Then
        ' This value selected
        If Result(InxRMax) <> "" Then
          Result(InxRMax) = Result(InxRMax) & Sep
        End If
        Result(InxRMax) = Result(InxRMax) & Value(InxVRCrnt)
      End If
    Next
    ' Treat InxResultCrnt as a little endian binary number
    ' and step its value by 1.  Ignore overflow.
    ' Values will be:
    '   000000000
    '   100000000
    '   010000000
    '   110000000
    '   001000000
    '   etc
    For InxVRCrnt = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
      If InxResultCrnt(InxVRCrnt) = 0 Then
        InxResultCrnt(InxVRCrnt) = 1
        Exit For
      Else
        InxResultCrnt(InxVRCrnt) = 0
      End If
    Next
  Loop

End Sub
```

**New section**

Nuclearman's explanation of the overflow is partially correct.  Data type Integer always specifies a 16-bit signed integer.  This is not dependent on the Excel version.  Arrays sizes are not a limiting issue.

The macro `GenerateCombinations` was originally written years ago when data type Integer was appropriate.  I failed to notice these definitions:

```
Dim InxRMax As Integer           ' Maximum used entry in array Result
Dim InxVRCrnt As Integer         ' Working index into arrays Value and InxResultCrnt
```

They should be replaced by:

```
Dim InxRMax As Long              ' Maximum used entry in array Result
Dim InxVRCrnt As Long            ' Working index into arrays Value and InxResultCrnt
```

Data type Long specifies a 32-bit signed integer which will fix the immediate problem.

Note: you should never use data type Integer on 32 or 64-bit computers because 16-bit integer require special (slow) processing.

The table below reveals the hidden problem:

```
                                Duration
Number of        Number of      of macro
Keys/Values    combinations    in seconds
 5                       32       0.17
10                    1,024       0.24
15                   32,768       3.86
16                   65,536       8.02
17                  131,072      16.95
18                  262,144      33.04
19                  524,288      67.82
20                1,048,576     142.82
25               33,554,432 
30            1,073,741,824 
31            2,147,483,648
```

The number of combinations of N values is 2^N.  My macro is generating every possible combination and storing it as a string in an array.  With 15 values that array has 32,768 entries which is one more than the maximum value for a 16-bit signed integer.

I corrected the data type of `InxRMax` to Long and timed the macro for different numbers of values.  You can see that the duration approximately doubles for each extra value.  I am not willing to test the maco with 21 or more values.  The macro would have failed again if I had tried 31 values and waited until it had finished.

If this is a one-off exercise and you have than 20 values, this approach may still be appropriate because you can leave the macro running and do something else for 6, 12, 24 or 48 minutes.  This approach will not be appropriate if you have more than a few values and you want to run the macro repeatedly fot different sets of values.

Comment: Thanks Tony! I don´t understand every step but I tried it and it works great, the strange thing is that it´s really fast up to 15 elements, but then I get an overflow.

Comment: I will test with a larger number of key/values and get back to you.

Comment: At 16 elements 2^16 cells are used, but older versions of excel only allow for 2^16-1 cells. Array lengths are also probably limited by this.

Comment: @Luis  I have added a new section which explains why you got the overflow.  Nuclearman's explanation is only partially correct. I explain how to fix the overflow with 15 values. I also show how the duration of the macro increases with larger numbers of values.  I have ideas for an alternative approach if this approach does not meet your requirements.

Comment: I must have been looking in the wrong place as the source I checked showed a 32 bit integer type though that was my third guess as to the issue. It also might be good to formulate this so you can use the [polynominal-time approximate algorithm for subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm). Via setting `s = Max` and solving `Min = (1 − c)s` for c. If the min/max range is large enough to justify it's use.

Comment: Thanks for the update Tony, I´m learning a lot from this!
In scenarios involving a larger sample, do you think @Nuclearman suggestion would improve the time? Where is the trade off there if there´s any?
I´ve to say thanks again.

Comment: Alternatively you could also use the O(2^(N/2)) algorithm for subset sum. The time improvement is highly dependent on the size of the gap between min and max the larger the gap the better the performance. In your example it's not terribly helpful and you'd be better off using the O(2^(N/2)) algorithm to improve things.

Comment: @Luis  Given values A to Z, my macro generates every possible combination of the values A to Z.  This is allows me to keep the different steps completely separate which gives (relative) simplicity but with the price that the duration doubles for each extra value.  The problem with my macro is that if A+B > Maximum and C to Z are positive then the time to examine A+B+C, A+B+D, etc is wasted. An algorithm that  ignored A+B+anything positive would be quicker.

Comment: @Nuclearman  Why not post an answer based on your referenced algorithm?

Comment: I'll do so once I have more examples since I'm far more familiar with the concepts than I am with VBA (excel or otherwise).

Comment: @Nuclearman, what do you mean with "more examples"?
If you´re talking about the A/B columns content, that can be any group of 20, 30 random numbers let´s say between -100 and 1000. 
Is that what you were talking about?
Thanks!

Comment: I outlined what I meant as a comment to the question itself. That gets me about half of what I'd need. How about the target min/max?

Comment: @Nuclearman The target range should be (x-a; x+a), being a<=0.5.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Second answer**

My first answer is, I believe, about as simple a solution as is possible:

1. The steps are completely separate making then easier to code and understand.
2. Most of the work is within a routine I have used before and will no doubt use again.
3. Has an acceptable duration for small numbers of items.
4. Is not affected by having both positive and negative values.

This answer uses a different approach.  The steps are not separate, making them more complicated, and I doubt I have a future use for this code.  The approach is affected by having negative numbers but I have coded around that issue.  The big advantage is that the duration is substantially reduced.

I do not believe this is an implementation of the algorithm referenced by Nuclearman.  Apparently that algorithm requires all numbers to be positive and involves a sort per element; neither of which is true for my approach.

The duration of my macro is dependent on the range of values and I lack the mathematical skill to determine an expected upper value for the duration.  The table below gives indicative durations:

```
                           Duration of    Duration of    Number of
Number of    Number of      approach 1     approach 2    combinations
Keys/Values  combinations   in seconds     in seconds    tested
 1                    2            
 2                    4            
 3                    8            
 4                   16            
 5                   32           0.17           0.20         29
 6                   64            
 7                  128            
 8                  256            
 9                  512            
10                1,024           0.24           0.27        100
11                2,048            
12                4,096            
13                8,192            
14               16,384            
15               32,768           3.86           0.41     10,021
16               65,536           8.02           0.64     18,586
17              131,072          16.95           0.70     21,483
18              262,144          33.04           0.76     24,492
19              524,288          67.82           0.83     28,603
20            1,048,576         142.82           0.99     34,364
21            2,097,152            
22            4,194,304            
23            8,388,608            
24           16,777,216            
25           33,554,432            
26           67,108,864                          8.97    315,766
```

The duration of approach 1 doubles with each extra item because it tests every possible combination.  Approach 2 is more complicated and is slower with smaller number of items but by only testing a small proportion of the possible combinations it is the quicker approach with larger number of items.  I have used the same data for the Approach 1 and 2 tests so I believe this gives an indication of durations you might expect.

The first step in approach 2 is to sort the KeyValue table into ascending order by value.

The next step is to import the KeyValue table from the worksheet to an array.  This could have been done with Approach 1 but that approach was all about simplicity while Approach 2 is about doing anything to reduce the duration.

Suppose a combination is a selection from Value(1) to Value(N).  If adding Value(N+1) to the combination takes the total over the maximum then adding any later value would also take the total over the maximum because all later values are larger than Value(N+1).  Therefore, any addition to this combination will take it over the maximum total and no extension need be considered.

I have been much more careful with the documentation within the Approach 2 macros.  I believe I have full explained the approach and its implementation.  However, come back with questions if necessary.

```
Option Explicit

  ' * I have a system for allocating names to my constants and variables.
  '   I can look at macros I wrote years ago and immediately know the
  '   purpose of the variables. This is a real help if I need to enhance
  '   an old macro.
  ' * If you do not like my system, develop your own.
  ' * My names are a sequence of words each of which reduces the scope
  '   of the variable.
  ' * Typically, the first word identified the purpose:
  '     Inx  index into a 1D array
  '     Col  a column of a worksheet or a 2D array
  '     Row  a row of a worksheet or a 2D array
  '     Wsht something to do with a worksheet
  ' * If I have more than worksheet, I will have a keyword to identify
  '   which worksheet a variable is used for:
  '     ColSrc   a column of the source worksheet
  '     RowRslt  a row of a results worksheet
  '     ColKV    a column of the KeyValue array

  ' Although most constants are only used by one routine, some are used by
  ' more than one. I have defined all as global so all constants are together.
  ' ==========================================================================

  ' * Changes values if the minimum and maximum values are moved.
  ' * The code assumes both values are in the Source worksheet.
  Const CellSrcMin As String = "C3"
  Const CellSrcMax As String = "D3"

  ' * The leftmost column will always be 1 no matter what
  '   columns the KeyValue table occupies in the worksheet
  ' * Reverse values if the columns are swapped
  Const ColKVKey As Long = 1
  Const ColKVValue As Long = 2

  ' * Reverse values if the columns are swapped
  Const ColRsltValue As String = "A"
  Const ColRsltExpnKey As String = "B"
  Const ColRsltExpnValue As String = "C"

  ' * Change both of these constants if the KeyValue table
  '   does not start in column A of the worksheet
  Const ColSrcKVFirst As String = "A"
  Const ColSrcKVLast As String = "B"

  ' * Change both of these constants if the KeyValue table
  '   does not start in column A of the worksheet
  ' * Reverse values if the columns are swapped
  Const ColSrcKVKey As String = "A"
  Const ColSrcKVValue As String = "B"

  ' Increase value if a second or third header row is added
  ' Reduce value to 1 if there is no header row
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2

  ' Change values to match worksheet names
  Const WshtRsltName As String = "Result"
  Const WshSrcName As String = "Source"

  ' Variables used by more than one routine
  ' =======================================

  ' The KeyValue table will be loaded from the source worksheet to this
  ' variant as a 2D array
  Dim KeyValue As Variant

  ' Row in results worksheet to which the next result will be written
  Dim RowRsltNext As Long

Sub Control2()

  ' If one of the tests of the last entry in the pending arrays
  ' indicate that entry should be deleted, set to True.
  Dim DeleteEntry As Boolean

  ' The current last used entry in the pending arrays
  Dim InxPendingCrntMax As Long

  ' Number of combinations tested
  Dim NumTested As Long

  ' * The Pending arrays hold information about combinations that are pending;
  '   that is, combinations that have not been accepted as having an in-range
  '   total and have not been rejected as having an above maximum total.
  ' * The value of an entry in PendingWhichKeys might be "++-+". This means
  '   that this combination contains the first, second and fourth values but not
  '   the third. The corresponding entry in PendingTotal will contain the total
  '   of the first, second and fourth values.
  Dim PendingWhichKeys() As String
  Dim PendingTotal() As Double

  ' * Rows within KeyValue.
  ' * RowKVFirst is the control variable for the outer For-Loop. A value of N
  '   means this repeat considers combinations that start with the Nth value.
  ' * RowKVCrnt is used in the inner Do-Loop. It is set to the number of the
  '   next row to be considered for addition to a combination.
  Dim RowKVFirst As Long
  Dim RowKVCrnt As Long

  ' The last row of the KeyValue table within the source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcDataLast As Long

  ' Used to calculate the duration of a run.  Set by Timer to the number of
  ' seconds since midnight. The value includes fractions of a second but I
  ' cannot find any documentation that specifies how accurate the time is.
  ' I suspect it depends on the clock speed.  Anyway, with OS and other
  ' background routines running at any time, no timings are that accurate.
  Dim TimeStart As Double

  ' The minimum and maximum values are copied from the
  ' source worksheet to these variables.
  Dim TotalMax As Double
  Dim TotalMin As Double

  TimeStart = Timer

  With Worksheets(WshSrcName)

    ' Find last row in KeyValue table
    RowSrcDataLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcKVKey).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Sort KeyValue table within worksheet by value
    .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, ColSrcKVKey), _
           .Cells(RowSrcDataLast, ColSrcKVValue)) _
       .Sort Key1:=.Range(ColSrcKVValue & RowSrcDataFirst), _
             Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, _
             MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
             DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    ' KeyValue is of data type Variant (meaning it can hold anything).
    ' This statement loads all the data from a range and places it in KeyValue
    ' as a 2D array. The first dimension will be for rows and the second for
    ' columns. Both lower bounds will be 1 regardless of where the range was
    ' located.
    KeyValue = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, ColSrcKVFirst), _
                     .Cells(RowSrcDataLast, ColSrcKVLast)).Value

    ' Get the minimum and maximum required values
    TotalMin = .Range(CellSrcMin).Value
    TotalMax = .Range(CellSrcMax).Value

  End With

  ' Initialise result worksheet
  With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    With .Range("A1")
      .Value = "Total"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    .Range("B1").Value = "Key Expn"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Value Expn"
    .Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
    ' This value will be overwritten if any combination gives an acceptable value
    .Range("A2").Value = "No combination gives a total in the range " & _
                         TotalMin & " to " & TotalMax
  End With
  RowRsltNext = 2

  ' The maximum pending entries is the number of rows in the KeyValue table
  ReDim PendingWhichKeys(1 To UBound(KeyValue, 1))
  ReDim PendingTotal(1 To UBound(KeyValue, 1))

  NumTested = 0

  ' Each repeat of this loop considers the combinations that
  ' start with the KeyValue from RowKVFirst.
  For RowKVFirst = 1 To UBound(KeyValue, 1)

    If KeyValue(RowKVFirst, ColKVValue) > TotalMax Then
      ' The value of the first entry is above the maximum acceptable value.
      ' Any further values will be even larger so there are no more combinations
      ' that could be acceptable
      Exit For
    End If

    ' Create entries in the pending arrays for the shortest combination
    ' being considered during this repeat of the outer loop.
    PendingWhichKeys(1) = "+"
    PendingTotal(1) = KeyValue(RowKVFirst, ColKVValue)
    InxPendingCrntMax = 1        ' The last currently used entry
    NumTested = NumTested + 1

    Do While InxPendingCrntMax > 0
      ' Examine last entry in pending arrays:
      '  * if total is within range, add entry to results worksheet
      '  * if adding the value of the next KeyValue would cause the total
      '    to exceed the maximum, delete entry from pending arrays
      '  * if the last row of the KeyValue table has been considered for
      '    inclusion in the combination, delete entry from pending arrays
      '  * if the entry is not to be deleted:
      '      * create new entry in pending arrays.
      '      * copy the previous last entry to this new entry but with an
      '        extra "-" at the end of the PendingWhichKeys entry
      '      * Add "+" to end of PendingWhichKeys entry and add appropriate
      '        value to PendingTotal entry

      If PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax) >= TotalMin And _
         PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax) <= TotalMax Then
        ' This is an acceptable value
        If Right(PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax), 1) = "+" Then
          ' This combination has not been output before
          Call OutputResult(RowKVFirst, PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax), _
               PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax))
        End If
      End If

      DeleteEntry = False
      ' Identify next row of KeyValue that could be added to combination
      RowKVCrnt = RowKVFirst + Len(PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax))
      If RowKVCrnt > UBound(KeyValue, 1) Then
        ' All rows have been considered for addition to this combination
        DeleteEntry = True
      ElseIf PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax) + KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue) _
                                                          > TotalMax Then
        ' Adding another value to this combination would cause it to exceed
        ' the maximum value.  Because of the sort, any other values will be
        ' larger than the current value so no extension to this combination
        ' need be considered.
        DeleteEntry = True
      End If

      If DeleteEntry Then
        ' Abandon this combination
        InxPendingCrntMax = InxPendingCrntMax - 1
      Else
        ' Extend this combination
        ' Create new combination based on non-addition of current row
        ' to current combination
        PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax + 1) = _
                                            PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax) & "-"
        PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax + 1) = PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax)
        ' Add current row to existing combination
        PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax) = _
                                            PendingWhichKeys(InxPendingCrntMax) & "+"
        PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax) = PendingTotal(InxPendingCrntMax) + _
                                                      KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue)
        InxPendingCrntMax = InxPendingCrntMax + 1
        ' I consider both the new and the amended entries as new tests
        NumTested = NumTested + 2
      End If
    Loop
  Next

  With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
    .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
  End With

  Debug.Print "Number keys " & UBound(KeyValue, 1)
  Debug.Print "Number tested " & NumTested
  Debug.Print "Duration: " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "#,##0.00")

End Sub
Sub OutputResult(ByVal RowKVFirst As Long, ByVal WhichKeys As String, _
                 ByVal Total As Double)

  ' Output a result to result worksheet

  ' Global variables:
  '  * KeyValue
  '  * RowRsltNext

  ' Parameters:
  '  * RowKVFirst  Identifies the first row in KeyValue being considered
  '                currently. KeyValues in rows 1 to RowKVFirst-1 are not
  '                within the current combination.
  '  * WhichKeys   Identifies which KeyValues are present in the current
  '                combination.  If the value is "++-+" then:
  '                 * Row RowKVFirst   selected
  '                 * Row RowKVFirst+1 selected
  '                 * Row RowKVFirst+2 not selected
  '                 * Row RowKVFirst+3 selected
  '                 * Row RowKVFirst+4, if present, and any following rows
  '                   not selected
  '  * Total       The total value of the current combination.

  Dim ExpnKey As String
  Dim ExpnValue As String
  Dim PosWhichKeys As Long
  Dim RowKVCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
    ' Output total for combination
    .Cells(RowRsltNext, ColRsltValue) = Total
    ' Create key string
    ' Get Key and Value from first row within combination
    ExpnKey = KeyValue(RowKVFirst, ColKVKey)
    ExpnValue = KeyValue(RowKVFirst, ColKVValue)
    ' Add keys and values from any other rows
    For PosWhichKeys = 2 To Len(WhichKeys)
      If Mid(WhichKeys, PosWhichKeys, 1) = "+" Then
        ' This rows is within combination
        RowKVCrnt = RowKVFirst + PosWhichKeys - 1
        ExpnKey = ExpnKey & "+" & KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVKey)
        ExpnValue = ExpnValue & "+" & KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue)
      End If
    Next
    .Cells(RowRsltNext, ColRsltExpnKey) = ExpnKey
    .Cells(RowRsltNext, ColRsltExpnValue) = ExpnValue
    RowRsltNext = RowRsltNext + 1
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks Tony, now I fully understand how this works.
The thing is, I´m still getting overflows for 2x elements. 
May be that it´s the limit via vba?
It´s clearly an optimized version of the one you posted before but the number of elements is still limited.

Comment: I can't say for certain but I strongly suspect your algorithm probably uses something akin to [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) which doesn't have an easily defined complexity. However, it is known to be rather efficient for certain types of problems. Also you might want to try using the range of values Luis mentioned above for your tests. **Luis:** Perhaps you should post what software versions (Excel/VBA) you are using. **Tony:** You also might want to post a screenshot of your testing excel spreadsheet, perhaps Luis is doing something slightly differently.

Comment: @Luis I have tested my new routine with your original data and up to 26 KeyValues.  It cannot be the same overflow because the code that gave it before has gone.  Where is the new overflow?  Can you post the data that ends in an overflow?

Comment: @Luis  The second approach is not an optimised version of the first. Few solutions can offer everything; there is usually a compromise. The first version was optimised for speed of implementation and reuses old code.  The second version is faster but uses a more complex approach that took longer to debug and the code is unlikely to be reusable.

Comment: @Nuclearman Your reference does not really identify the defining characteristics of the B&B approach. You could argue that I am searching a tree although that is not how I thought of it. I am not using recursion. I will consider added more explanation of the approach to the answer so you can give a more consider opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I did include a second article but while the first bit of it was the useful bit, but it's still interesting, so [Branch And Bound—Why Does It Work?](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/branch-and-bound-why-does-it-work/). [Branch and Bound Algorithms and Examples (PDF)](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Employees/jbj/heuristikker/TSPtext.pdf) seems like it might be more ideal for understanding. It's somewhat long, but I think you could probably see that your algorithm uses B&B just by reading the introduction.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks for the new references. I agree what I am doing is within the scope of B&B. I am glad the author of the article finds it difficult to describe. I can create a description of my implementation easily but my attempts to describe a logical description of the approach disintegrate.

Comment: Offtopic, just wanted to thank you both. I´m clearly adding introductory CS classes to my schedule next term.

Comment: **Luis:** Be sure to get some algorithms classes as well. Though you can also find a number of free books online. I also found Udacity's courses to be rather interesting. **Tony:** Out of curiosity, could you add to your answer how you went about testing the algorithm (selection of target range and values)? I crunched the numbers and looks like the O(2^(N/2)) algorithm might be better. Although, it might be possible to use B&B on that algorithm as well. The issue being that the `((number of keys)/2)-root of (the combinations tested)` is a fair bit higher than 2, making it worst than `2^(N/2)`.

Comment: @Nuclearman This is my answer so I am told about any comment posted against it. For everyone else you must include @ Username if they are to be told.  Luis may not know of your latest posting.  PS I have a space between @ and Username because I cannot post the comment without a space there since the system thinks I am talking to two people with one comment which is not allowed.

Comment: @Nuclearman I suspect you think I have put more thought into these solutions than I have. Over 50 years ago my class had a homework in which we had to lists all the combinations of A-D, A-E, A-F and so on. I assume it was preparation for a lesson on the mathematics of combinations. My understanding was that I was the only to have complete sets of combinations. I mentally mapped the binary numbers 0000-1111 against ABCD and for each combination selected the letters against a 1. So 0000="", 0001="D", 0010="C", 0011="CD". To me this had seemed an easy and systematic approach.

Comment: @Nuclearman  At some time I have needed to generate combinations and had coded a routine that used this approach. For my first solution, I just used code I had to hand. For small sets and one-off generation from larger sets it gives acceptable durations. Only when Luis indicated he needed a reduced duration did I consider other techniques. The technique I used for the second solution was the first idea that occurred to me. It gave acceptable results for the set size that Luis mentioned. I am not trying for an optimal solution merely an acceptable solution. I was taught not to over engineer.

Comment: @Luis Until I know which instruction gives the overflow, I can do nothing more for you. The only overflow I can imagine is to have more acceptable results than there are rows in a worksheet.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the values are supposed to be from something like -1000 to 1000 (Luis seems to have deleted the comment). So you might have issues if you only use 1 thru N. Your labeling is quite valid as long as the values of A, B and C aren't simply 1, 2 and 3 rather than say 10,-375, and 200. Not to mention your max possible sum would be significantly lower which *might* explain the lack of overflow.

Comment: @Nuclearman  I am holding totals as doubles (8 byte floating point) with a range of ±10^308 so I do not believe I can get overflow there.  I have tried with 30 values between -1, 000 and +1,000 and a target range of 500±X.  Finding a value for X was tricky: too small and I got no in-range totals but too large and I ran out of rows for the results.  Running out of rows does not give “overflow” as I thought but “Application-defined or object-defined error”.

Comment: Sounds about right then. Not sure where the issue could be.

Comment: @Nuclearman, Tony, I don't know why my comment is not there anymore. My value range is very Wide, from millions (up to 2-4), to -300,000. But my target range is very specific. The difference between max and min should be not more than 0,3 and it's there just to cover sum of small roundings. I'll run a trial tonight and Will Let you know where is the overflow I get.

Comment: @Nuclearman, Tony, sorry I couldn´t check this yesterday as I said.
I tested it today and here´s is where I got the overflow:
  "NumTested = NumTested + 2"
I used 43 values, all =RANDBETWEEN(-300000,1000000) and target was 653441 (as min and max).

Comment: @Luis You keep moving the goal posts. In your question, you have 5 rows for which a brute-force, test-every-combination approach is adequate. You then said you had 10-15 rows for which a test-every-combination approach is still adequate (duration 4 seconds) but the duration doubles for every extra row. I devised a second approach which cuts down on the number of combinations tested. With a 20 row dataset, it could find all near-target combinations in 9 seconds. You now have a dataset with 43 rows. ...

Comment: @Luis You now have a dataset with 43 rows. The overflow occurred because NumTested is a 32-bit signed Long variable and with 43 rows, you reached 2^31 (2,147,483,648) combinations tested. You can avoid the overflow by removing NumTested and all statements that reference it since it is only a diagnostic aid. However, although approach 2 is better that a test-every-combination it is not good enough for a dataset of 43 rows and a value range of -300K to 1,000K. I have devised a better approach for discarding unpromising combinations.

Comment: @Luis I have devised a better approach for discarding unpromising combinations. With a dataset of 43 rows and a value range of -300K to 1,000K, it found 10 on-target combinations in about 5 minutes but then looped for another 55 minutes; I do not know why. It is approaching 23:00 for me so I will not do any more tonight. I will debug tomorrow if this sound interesting.

Comment: @Luis I have done a little more debugging and my new approach is substantially better than I thought at first.  It will find 10 on-target combinations in 57 seconds, 20 in 1 minutes 57 seconds, 30 in 3:34 and 40 in 5:35.  Are you interested?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Hi Tony, sorry I didn´t answer before! I took a couple of days off work and didn´t check this! That approach sounds interesting for sure! What would you do to achieve that much shorter time?

Answer (score 1):

**Code for Approach 3 - Part 1**

The formatted code is too big for a single answer.  Load part 1 followied by part 2 to their own module.

```
Option Explicit
  ' * Address of cell holding target value
  ' * Changes value if the target value is moved.
  ' * The code assumes both values are in the Source worksheet.
  Const CellSrcTgt As String = "C2"

  ' * Column numbers within KeyValue table once
  ' * The leftmost column will always be 1 no matter what
  '   columns the KeyValue table occupies in the worksheet
  ' * Reverse values if the columns are swapped
  Const ColKVKey As Long = 1
  Const ColKVValue As Long = 2

  ' * Change values if the columns are swapped.
  ' * Increase ColRsltMax if a new column is added
  ' * Providing the table in the worksheet starts in column 1, column numbers
  '   are the same in the array and the worksheet.  If the worksheet table
  '   does not start in column 1, two sets of column numbers constants will be
  '   required and all code referencing these constants will require review.
  Const ColRsltTotal As Long = 1
  Const ColRsltDiffAbs As Long = 2
  Const ColRsltExpnKey As Long = 3
  Const ColRsltExpnValue As Long = 4
  Const ColRsltMax As Long = 4

  ' These specify the columns with the Pending array so the code is
  ' self-documenting.  The Pending array is internal to this set of routine
  ' so there is no need to change theses values
  Const ColPendExpn As Long = 1
  Const ColPendDiff As Long = 2
  Const ColPendMax As Long = 2

  ' * Change both of these constants if the KeyValue table
  '   does not start in column A of the worksheet
  Const ColSrcKVFirst As String = "A"
  Const ColSrcKVLast As String = "B"

  ' * Change both of these constants if the KeyValue table
  '   does not start in column A of the worksheet
  ' * Reverse values if the columns are swapped
  Const ColSrcKVKey As String = "A"
  Const ColSrcKVValue As String = "B"

  ' Defines the first row within the results worksheet of the range to which
  ' the Results array is written. Change if the number of header rows changes.
  Const RowRsltWshtDataFirst As Long = 2

  ' Increase value if a second or third header row is added
  ' Reduce value to 1 if there is no header row
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2

  ' Change values to match your worksheet names
  Const WshtRsltName As String = "Result"
  Const WshSrcName As String = "Source"

  ' Variables used by more than one routine
  ' =======================================

  ' The KeyValue table will be loaded from the source worksheet to this
  ' variant as a 2D array
  Dim KeyValue As Variant

'#  ' Current row number for worksheet Diag
'#  Dim RowDiagCrnt As Long

Sub Control3()

  ' Find the combinations of items from the KeyValue tables whose total values
  ' are closest to the target total.

'#  Dim ExpnKeyCrnt As String
'#  Dim ExpnValueCrnt As String

  ' While duplicating a pending row, its contents are held in these variable
  Dim PendExpnCrnt As String
  Dim PendDiffCrnt As Long

  ' * The Pending array hold information about combinations that are pending;
  '   that is, combinations that are on target or might become on target after
  '   addition of further items to the combination.
  ' * The array is redimensioned as a 2D array with 50,000 rows and 2 columns.
  '   Choice of 50,000 as the number of rows is arbitrary; less might be
  '   adequate and more might be better.
  ' * Typically with 2D arrays the first dimension is for columns and the
  '   second for rows so the number of rows can be increased or decreased with
  '   "ReDim Preserve".  Arrays that are read from or are written to worksheets
  '   must have the columns and rows reversed.  Pending is both written to and
  '   read from the worksheet Sort.
  ' * Column 1 holds detains of the combination as a string of the form
  '   "--+-+". The string has one "-" or "+" for every entry in the KeyValue
  '   table. If the Nth character in the string is "+", the Nth entry in the
  '   KeyValue table is included in the combination.
  ' * Column 2 holds TargetValue - TotalOfCombination.
  Dim Pending() As Variant

  Dim PosExpn As Long

  ' * Potential results are accumulated in this array.
  ' * The number of rows is defined by RowArrRsltsMax.
  ' * Initially every possible combination is added at the bottom of this
  '   array. Once the array is full, a new combination overwrites the
  '   previously stored combination with the worst total if the new combination
  '   has a better total. In this context, a better total is closer to the
  '   target total than a worse one.
  ' * Traditionally 2D arrays have columns as the first dimension and rows as
  '   the second dimension.  Arrays to be written to a worksheet must have their
  '   dimensions the other way round. After each new result is added to this
  '   array, the array is written to the results rworksheet and the workbook
  '   saved. This slows the macro but means that if it is terminated with the
  '   Task Manager any results found are already saved to disc.
  Dim Result() As Variant

  Dim RowKVCrnt As Long           ' Current row within KeyValue
  Dim RowKVFirstPositive As Long  ' First row within KeyValue with a +ve value

  Dim RowPendCrnt As Long     ' The current row in Pending
  Dim RowPendCrntMax As Long  ' The current last used row in Pending
  Dim RowPendMaxMax As Long   ' The last ever used row in Pending

  ' Defines the maximum number of results that will be accumulated
  Const RowRsltArrMax As Long = 40

  ' Row in array Result to which the next result will be written providing
  ' RowArrRsltNext < RowArrRsltMax.  Once RowArrRsltNext = RowArrRsltMax,
  ' any new combination overwrites an existing row.
  Dim RowRsltArrNext As Long
  ' Control variable for For-Loop
  Dim RowRsltArrCrnt As Long

  ' The last row of the KeyValue table within the source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcDataLast As Long

  ' Used to calculate the duration of a run.  Set by Timer to the number of
  ' seconds since midnight. The value includes fractions of a second but I
  ' cannot find any documentation that specifies how accurate the time is.
  ' I suspect it depends on the clock speed.  Anyway, with OS and other
  ' background routines running at any time, no timings are that accurate.
  Dim TimeStart As Double

  Dim TotalNegative As Long   ' The total of all negative values
  Dim TotalPositive As Long   ' The total of all posative values
  Dim TotalTgt As Long        ' The target value is copied from the source
                              ' worksheet to this variable.
  TimeStart = Timer

  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.StatusBar = "No results found so far"

  With Worksheets(WshSrcName)

    ' Find last row in KeyValue table
    RowSrcDataLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcKVKey).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Sort KeyValue table within worksheet by value
    .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, ColSrcKVKey), _
           .Cells(RowSrcDataLast, ColSrcKVValue)) _
       .Sort Key1:=.Range(ColSrcKVValue & RowSrcDataFirst), _
             Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, _
             MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
             DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    ' KeyValue is of data type Variant (meaning it can hold anything).
    ' This statement loads all the data from a range and places it in KeyValue
    ' as a 2D array. The first dimension will be for rows and the second for
    ' columns. Both lower bounds will be 1 regardless of where the range was
    ' located.
    KeyValue = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, ColSrcKVFirst), _
                     .Cells(RowSrcDataLast, ColSrcKVLast)).Value

    ' Get the target value
    TotalTgt = .Range(CellSrcTgt).Value

  End With

  ' Gather information about the KeyValue table
  TotalNegative = 0
  For RowKVCrnt = 1 To UBound(KeyValue, 1)
    If KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue) >= 0 Then
      ' Treat a value of zero as positive.  Arbitrary choice.
      Exit For
    End If
    TotalNegative = TotalNegative + KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue)
  Next
  RowKVFirstPositive = RowKVCrnt
  TotalPositive = 0
  For RowKVCrnt = RowKVCrnt To UBound(KeyValue, 1)
    TotalPositive = TotalPositive + KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue)
  Next

  ' Initialise result worksheet
  With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    With .Cells(1, ColRsltTotal)
      .Value = "Total"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    With .Cells(1, ColRsltDiffAbs)
      .Value = "Abs diff"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    .Cells(1, ColRsltExpnKey) = "Key Expn"
    .Cells(1, ColRsltExpnValue).Value = "Value Expn"
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, ColRsltMax)).Font.Bold = True
    .Columns(ColRsltTotal).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Columns(ColRsltDiffAbs).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    ' This value will be overwritten if any combination gives an acceptable value
    .Range("A2").Value = "No combinations found"
  End With
  RowRsltArrNext = 1

  ' The technique used does not require large amounts of memory for pending
  ' combinations.  During testing the maximum number of rows used was 312 with
  ' RowRsltArrMax = 400.
  ReDim Pending(1 To 1000, 1 To ColPendMax)
  ReDim Result(1 To RowRsltArrMax, 1 To ColRsltMax)

  ' Seed Pending with one combination for every row in the
  ' KeyValue table with a positive value
  RowPendCrntMax = 0
  For RowKVCrnt = RowKVFirstPositive To UBound(KeyValue, 1)
    RowPendCrntMax = RowPendCrntMax + 1
    Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn) = String(RowKVCrnt - 1, "-") & "+" & _
                                           String(UBound(KeyValue, 1) - RowKVCrnt, "-")
    Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendDiff) = TotalTgt - KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue)
  Next
  RowPendMaxMax = RowPendCrntMax

'#  RowDiagCrnt = 1
'#  With Worksheets("Diag")
'#    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
'#    .Cells.ClearFormats
'#    .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 1).Value = "Pending"
'#    With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2)
'#      .Value = "Index"
'#      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#    End With
'#    .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3).Value = "Expn"
'#    .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4).Value = "Key Expn"
'#    .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = "Value Expn"
'#    With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6)
'#      .Value = "Total"
'#      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#    End With
'#    .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 7).Value = "Diff"
'#    RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#    For RowPendCrnt = 1 To RowPendCrntMax
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2).Value = RowPendCrnt
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3)
'#        .Value = Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendExpn)
'#        .Font.Name = "Courier New"
'#      End With
'#      Call GenExpn(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendExpn), ExpnKeyCrnt, ExpnValueCrnt)
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4).Value = ExpnKeyCrnt
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = "'" & ExpnValueCrnt
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6).Value = "=" & ExpnValueCrnt
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 7)
'#        .Value = Format(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendDiff), "#,##0")
'#      End With
'#      RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#    Next
'#  End With
'#  RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1

  Do While RowPendCrntMax > 0

    ' This combination may be one of those with a total nearest the target
    If Not OutputRslt(Pending, RowPendCrntMax, Result, RowRsltArrNext) Then
      ' Result is full of results with a total equal to the target total.
      ' No point searching any more because there is no room for more results.
      Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
      Debug.Print "Max Pending=" & RowPendMaxMax
      Debug.Print "Duration (sss.ss): " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "#,##0.00")
      TimeStart = Timer - TimeStart     ' Duration
      Debug.Print "Duration (m:ss): " & Format(TimeStart \ 60, "#,##0") & ":" & Format(TimeStart Mod 60, "00")
      Call MsgBox("Result worksheet is full of on-target results.", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    PendExpnCrnt = Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn)
    PendDiffCrnt = Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendDiff)

    ' Remove this combination from the Pending array.
    ' New copies will be added if appropriate.
    RowPendCrntMax = RowPendCrntMax - 1

    Select Case PendDiffCrnt
      Case Is < 0
        ' * The current total for this row is above the target.
        ' * Create a new combination for every negative value that can be
        '   added.
        ' * Negative values can only be added after any existing negative
        '   values to avoid creating multiple copies of the same combination.
        ' * An expression is of the form "+--+--+" with the position of each
        '   "+" or "-" corresponding to a row in KeyValue
        For PosExpn = RowKVFirstPositive - 1 To 1 Step -1
          If Mid(PendExpnCrnt, PosExpn, 1) = "-" Then
            ' This negative value has not been added
            RowPendCrntMax = RowPendCrntMax + 1
            If PosExpn = 1 Then
              ' "+" replaces first "-"
              Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn) = "+" & Mid(PendExpnCrnt, 2)
            Else
              ' "+" replaces a "-" in the middle
              Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn) = _
                                         Mid(PendExpnCrnt, 1, PosExpn - 1) & _
                                         "+" & _
                                         Mid(PendExpnCrnt, PosExpn + 1)
            End If
            ' KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue) is negative so subtracting it
            ' will increase PendDiffCrnt.
            Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendDiff) = _
                                PendDiffCrnt - KeyValue(PosExpn, ColKVValue)
          Else
            ' This negative value is already within the combination
            ' so no more negative value can be added
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If RowPendMaxMax < RowPendCrntMax Then
          RowPendMaxMax = RowPendCrntMax
        End If
      Case Is >= 0
        ' The current total for this row is equal to or below the target
        ' * Create a new combination for every positive value that can be
        '   added.
        ' * Positive values can only be added after any existing positive
        '   values to avoid creating multiple copies of the same combination.
        ' * An expression is of the form "+--+--+" with the position of each
        '   "+" or "-" corresponding to a row in KeyValue
        For PosExpn = UBound(KeyValue, 1) To RowKVFirstPositive Step -1
          If Mid(PendExpnCrnt, PosExpn, 1) = "-" Then
            ' This positive value has not been added
            RowPendCrntMax = RowPendCrntMax + 1
            If PosExpn = UBound(KeyValue, 1) Then
              ' "+" replaces final "-"
              Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn) = Mid(PendExpnCrnt, 1, Len(PendExpnCrnt) - 1) & "+"
            Else
              ' "+" replaces a "-" in the middle
              Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendExpn) = _
                                         Mid(PendExpnCrnt, 1, PosExpn - 1) & _
                                         "+" & _
                                         Mid(PendExpnCrnt, PosExpn + 1)
            End If
            ' KeyValue(RowKVCrnt, ColKVValue) is positive so subtracting it
            ' will reduce PendDiffCrnt.
            Pending(RowPendCrntMax, ColPendDiff) = _
                                PendDiffCrnt - KeyValue(PosExpn, ColKVValue)
          Else
            ' This positive value is already within the combination
            ' so no more positive value can be added
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If RowPendMaxMax < RowPendCrntMax Then
          RowPendMaxMax = RowPendCrntMax
        End If
    End Select

'#    With Worksheets("Diag")
'#
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 1).Value = "Result"
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2)
'#        .Value = "Index"
'#        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#      End With
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3)
'#        .Value = "Total"
'#        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#      End With
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4)
'#        .Value = "Abs diff"
'#        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#      End With
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = "Key Expn"
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6).Value = "Value Expn"
'#      RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#      For RowRsltArrCrnt = 1 To UBound(Result, 1)
'#        If RowRsltArrCrnt < RowRsltArrNext Then
'#          .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2).Value = RowRsltArrCrnt
'#          With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3)
'#            .Value = Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltTotal)
'#            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
'#          End With
'#          With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4)
'#            .Value = Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltDiffAbs)
'#            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
'#          End With
'#          .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltExpnKey)
'#          .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6).Value = Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltExpnValue)
'#        RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#        End If
'#      Next
'#
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 1).Value = "Pending"
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2)
'#        .Value = "Index"
'#        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#      End With
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3).Value = "Expn"
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4).Value = "Key Expn"
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = "Value Expn"
'#      With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6)
'#        .Value = "Total"
'#        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'#      End With
'#      .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 7).Value = "Diff"
'#      RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#      For RowPendCrnt = 1 To RowPendCrntMax
'#        .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 2).Value = RowPendCrnt
'#        With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 3)
'#          .Value = Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendExpn)
'#          .Font.Name = "Courier New"
'#        End With
'#        Call GenExpn(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendExpn), ExpnKeyCrnt, ExpnValueCrnt)
'#        .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 4).Value = ExpnKeyCrnt
'#        .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 5).Value = "'" & ExpnValueCrnt
'#        .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 6).Value = "=" & ExpnValueCrnt
'#        With .Cells(RowDiagCrnt, 7)
'#          .Value = Format(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendDiff), "#,##0")
'#        End With
'#        RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1
'#      Next
'#
'#    End With
'#    RowDiagCrnt = RowDiagCrnt + 1

  Loop  ' While RowPendCrntMax > 0

  ' Will only fall out the bottom of the loop if Result array not full of on-target
  ' results.  Final version of Result array will not have been written to worksheet

'#  With Worksheets("Diag")
'#    .Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2) + 2)).AutoFit
'#  End With

  With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
    .Range(.Cells(RowRsltWshtDataFirst, 1), _
           .Cells(RowRsltWshtDataFirst + UBound(Result, 1) - 1, _
                                         UBound(Result, 2))) = Result
    .Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2))).AutoFit
  End With
  ThisWorkbook.Save

  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Debug.Print "Max Pending=" & RowPendMaxMax

  Debug.Print "Duration (sss.ss): " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "#,##0.00")
  TimeStart = Timer - TimeStart
  Debug.Print "Duration (m:ss): " & Format(TimeStart \ 60, "#,##0") & ":" & Format(TimeStart Mod 60, "00")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code for Approach 3 - Part 2**

```
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = Code

End Function
Function OutputRslt(Pending, RowPendCrnt, Result, RowRsltArrNext) As Boolean

  ' * Output row Pending(RowPendCrnt) to array Result providing:
  '    *    Result is not full
  '    * or the new row's total is closer to the target than the existing row
  '         whose total is furthest from the target
  ' * The routine returns True unless Result is full of on-target rows.

  ' Static variables are private to this routine but their values are preserved
  ' from call to call.
  ' DiffAbsBest is only used for the status bar message
  ' DiffAbsWorst allows a quick check to see if a new result is to be saved
  Static DiffAbsBest As Long
  Static DiffAbsWorst As Long

  ' Not really important.  Allows the range for the results in the results
  ' worksheet to be calculated once rather than one per save.
  Static RngRsltWsht As Range

  ' The row holding the current worst result
  Static RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst As Long

  ' It appears that if a workbook is saved too frequently, Excel can end with a
  ' workbook that cannot be saved either with VBA or with the keyboard.  Used to
  ' ensure workbook is not saved more than once per minute but is saved
  ' regularly if changes are made.
  Static RecentChange As Boolean
  Static TimeLastSave As Double

  ' Values for the result current being saved
  Dim DiffAbsCrnt As Long
  Dim ExpnKeyCrnt As String
  Dim ExpnValueCrnt As String

  ' Control variable for For-Loop
  Dim RowRsltArrCrnt As Long

  DiffAbsCrnt = Abs(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendDiff))
  If RowRsltArrNext >= UBound(Result, 1) Then
    ' Result already full.
    If DiffAbsWorst = DiffAbsCrnt And DiffAbsCrnt = 0 Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Should not be possible to get here. Result being full of
      ' on-target totals should have been reported when last
      ' non-on-target row overwritten
      OutputRslt = False
      If RecentChange Then
        ' The array Results has been changed since it was last saved to the worksheet.
        RngRsltWsht.Value = Result
        Worksheets(WshtRsltName).Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2))).AutoFit
        RecentChange = False
        ThisWorkbook.Save  ' Might be better to remove this statement and let user save
        TimeLastSave = Timer
      End If
    ElseIf DiffAbsWorst > DiffAbsCrnt Then
      ' This result to be saved
    Else
      ' Do not keep this result
      OutputRslt = True     ' Result not full of on-target combinations
      If TimeLastSave > Timer Then
        Debug.Assert False
        ' Have gone over midnight.  Reset TimeLastSave
        TimeLastSave = Timer
      End If
      If TimeLastSave + 60# < Timer Then
        ' It has been at least one minute since the last save
        RngRsltWsht.Value = Result
        Worksheets(WshtRsltName).Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2))).AutoFit
        RecentChange = False
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        TimeLastSave = Timer
      End If
      Exit Function
    End If  ' DiffAbsWorst < DiffAbsCrnt | DiffAbsWorst = DiffAbsCrnt
  End If  ' RowRsltArrNext >= UBound(Result, 1) ' Result already full.

  ' This result will be kept either by adding it to a partially empty
  ' Result array or by overwriting an existing result whose total is
  ' further from the target than the new result total is.

  Call GenExpn(Pending(RowPendCrnt, ColPendExpn), ExpnKeyCrnt, ExpnValueCrnt)

  If RowRsltArrNext > UBound(Result, 1) Then
    ' Result already full but new combination is better than current worst
    ' "=" before ExpnValueCrnt to ensure treated as a formula by Excel
    Result(RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst, ColRsltTotal) = "=" & ExpnValueCrnt
    Result(RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst, ColRsltDiffAbs) = DiffAbsCrnt
    Result(RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst, ColRsltExpnKey) = ExpnKeyCrnt
    ' "'" before ExpnValueCrnt to ensure not treated as a formula by Excel
    Result(RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst, ColRsltExpnValue) = "'" & ExpnValueCrnt
    ' New result could be new best
    If DiffAbsBest > DiffAbsCrnt Then
      DiffAbsBest = DiffAbsCrnt
    End If
    ' There could be rows with a DiffAbs between the previous worst and the
    ' new row so search for new worst
    DiffAbsWorst = DiffAbsCrnt
    For RowRsltArrCrnt = 1 To UBound(Result, 1)
      If Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltDiffAbs) > DiffAbsWorst Then
        RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst = RowRsltArrCrnt
        DiffAbsWorst = Result(RowRsltArrCrnt, ColRsltDiffAbs)
      End If
    Next
  Else
    ' Result not full.  Add new result.
    If RowRsltArrNext = 1 Then
      ' First result being stored
      DiffAbsBest = DiffAbsCrnt
      DiffAbsWorst = DiffAbsCrnt
      RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst = RowRsltArrNext
      With Worksheets(WshtRsltName)
        Set RngRsltWsht = _
                 .Range(.Cells(RowRsltWshtDataFirst, 1), _
                        .Cells(RowRsltWshtDataFirst + UBound(Result, 1) - 1, _
                                                     UBound(Result, 2)))
      End With
      RecentChange = True
      TimeLastSave = Timer - 61#      ' Force initial save
    Else
      ' Subsequent result being stored
      If DiffAbsBest > DiffAbsCrnt Then
        DiffAbsBest = DiffAbsCrnt
      End If
      If DiffAbsWorst < DiffAbsCrnt Then
        DiffAbsWorst = DiffAbsCrnt
        RowRsltArrDiffAbsWorst = RowRsltArrNext
      End If
    End If
    ' "=" before ExpnValueCrnt to ensure treated as a formula by Excel
    Result(RowRsltArrNext, ColRsltTotal) = "=" & ExpnValueCrnt
    Result(RowRsltArrNext, ColRsltDiffAbs) = DiffAbsCrnt
    Result(RowRsltArrNext, ColRsltExpnKey) = ExpnKeyCrnt
    ' "'" before ExpnValueCrnt to ensure not treated as a formula by Excel
    Result(RowRsltArrNext, ColRsltExpnValue) = "'" & ExpnValueCrnt
    RowRsltArrNext = RowRsltArrNext + 1
  End If
  RecentChange = True

  Application.StatusBar = "Current results; closest to furthest from target: " _
                          & Format(DiffAbsBest, "#,##0") & " to " _
                          & Format(DiffAbsWorst, "#,##0")

  If RecentChange Then
    ' The array Results has been changed since it was last saved to the worksheet.
    If TimeLastSave > Timer Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Have gone over midnight.  Reset TimeLastSave
      TimeLastSave = Timer
    ElseIf TimeLastSave + 60# < Timer Then
      ' It has been at least one minute since the last save
      RngRsltWsht.Value = Result
      Worksheets(WshtRsltName).Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2))).AutoFit
      RecentChange = False
      ThisWorkbook.Save
      TimeLastSave = Timer
    End If
  End If

  If DiffAbsWorst = 0 Then
    OutputRslt = False      ' Result is full of on-target rows
    If RecentChange Then
      ' The array Results has been changed since it was last saved to the worksheet.
      RngRsltWsht.Value = Result
      Worksheets(WshtRsltName).Columns("A:" & ColNumToCode(UBound(Result, 2))).AutoFit
      RecentChange = False
      ThisWorkbook.Save  ' Might be better to remove this statement and let user save
      TimeLastSave = Timer
    End If
  Else
    OutputRslt = True
  End If

End Function
Sub GenExpn(ByVal PendExpn As String, ByRef RsltExpnKey As String, _
                                      ByRef RsltExpnValue As String)

  ' This routine generates RsltExpnKey and RsltExpnValue from PendExpn.

  ' PendExpn      A string of +s and -s representing a combination; for
  '               example "+--+--+"  Each + or - represents a row in
  '               the KeyValue table.  This combination is rows 1, 4 and 7.
  '               See definition of Pending array for more information
  ' RsltExpnKey   A string of the form "A+D+G" where A, B and G represent the
  '               keys from the rows identified by PendExpn.
  ' RsltExpnValue A string of the form "A+D+G" where A, B and G represent the
  '               values from the rows identified by PendExpn.

  Dim PosPE As Long

  RsltExpnKey = ""
  RsltExpnValue = ""

  For PosPE = 1 To Len(PendExpn)
    If Mid(PendExpn, PosPE, 1) = "+" Then
      If RsltExpnKey <> "" Then
        RsltExpnKey = RsltExpnKey & "+"
      End If
      RsltExpnKey = RsltExpnKey & KeyValue(PosPE, ColKVKey)
      If KeyValue(PosPE, ColKVValue) < 0 Then
        RsltExpnValue = RsltExpnValue & KeyValue(PosPE, ColKVValue)
      Else
        RsltExpnValue = RsltExpnValue & "+" & KeyValue(PosPE, ColKVValue)
      End If
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Third approach**

Approach 1 tested every possible combination.  This approach was easy and simple to code and would be adequate if there were not too many items in the set.  You have increased the number of items in your set so much that this approach is not viable.

Approach 2 and 3 both identify blind alleys to reduce the number of combinations tested.  Both approaches sort the set into ascending order but use different techniques for identifying blind alleys.  Once I had thought of approach 3, I was confident that it would be better than approach 2.  However, if there is a technique for proving approach 3 was the better approach without testing it, I am not clever enough to know it.

**Changes to solution 3 that are not related to the approach**

This section describes changes which are better ways of parameterising the macros and better ways of presenting the results and which would have been included in solution 1 and 2 if I had thought of them earlier.

I found having a range of targets, X ± A, where A is small awkward with smaller sets of keys.  Make A too small and I would get no matches.  Make A too large and I would get an over large number of matches.

I replaced a range with a single target and introduced a new parameter: the number of rows in the results table, `RowRsltArrMax`.  This means that instead of having to guess a range that will give me an acceptable number of results, the routine gives me the best `RowRsltArrMax` results or stops when it has found `RowRsltArrMax` on-target results.

Having a fixed number of results makes it easier to manage them.  Instead of writing each in-range result straight to the worksheet, I have an array ready to write to the worksheet.  The first `RowRsltArrMax` results are written to the array regardless of how on or off-target they are.  After that, any new result overwrites the previous worst result if it is better.  Here “better” means has a total that is closer to the target.

The routine now displays a message in the status bar:

```
Current results; closest to furthest from target: N to M
```

When I first created the third solution, I wrote the result array to the worksheet and saved the workbook each time the result array was updated.  I knew this would slow the macro but I thought having the best available results stored on disc in the event of a problem was worth the time.  However, I encountered a problem.  Sometimes the macro would stop on `ThisWorkbook.Save`.  The previous version of the workbook was correctly saved on disc but the version in memory could not be saved by VBA or via the keyboard.  I guessed this was something to do with how often the workbook was being saved and changed the routine so that the result array was written to the worksheet and the workbook saved once per minute if results better than those already saved are being found.  This change appears to have eliminated the save problem and revealed that saving the workbook every time a new result was saved was dramatically slowing the macro as shown by these results:

```
        ---- Duration (m:ss)-----
RowMax  Save every    Save every
          result    minute or two
    10      9:43       0:57
    20     20:08       1:57 
    30                 3:34
    40                 5:35
   100                16:56 
   363                67:27
```

These timings were with a KeyValue table containing 43 rows, random values between −300,000 and 1,000,000 and a target of 653,441.  The values for the final row of the above table were created by setting `RowRsltArrMax` so high that every combination summing to the target was found.

**Solution 3**

This image shows the top of the KeyValue table and the Target value.

[image: Top of the KeyValue table and the Target value]

This image shows the results worksheet after a run with `RowRsltArrMax = 10`.  The formula bar shows cell A2 = cell D2 except the A2 value has = at the beginning so Excel treats it as a formula while D2 has ' at the beginning so Excel treats it as a string.

[image: Results worksheet after a run with RowRsltArrMax = 10]

I have not found it easy to describe the technique behind solution 3.  In outline, the technique is to:

1. Seed a Pending table by creating one combination for each positive value.  Seeds are not created for keys with negative values to avoid generating the same combination more than one,
2. Loop repeating step 3 until either the Results table is full of on-target results or the Pending table is empty.
3. Remove the bottom row from the Pending table.  Consider adding it to the Results table as described in step 4.  Attempt to generate more combinations from it as discussed in step 5.
4. Every row removed from the Pending table is added to the Results table until it is full.  Once the Results table is full, the total of each new combination is compared against the worst total so far.  If the new total is better, the new row overwrites the worst row so far.
5. If the total of the new combination is less than the target total, generate one new combination for each positive value that is larger than any existing positive values within the combination.  If the total of the new combination is more than the target total, generate one new combination for each negative value that is larger than any existing negative values in the combinations.  The “larger” restrictions avoid generating the same combination more than once.

Macro `Control3` contains code that will output the contents of the Pending and Results tables to worksheet “Diag” before the first loop and at the end of every loop.  This code is current commented out (see statements starting ‘#) because it should only be used with small KeyValue tables.  If you removing the ‘#s and run the macro with a small set and a small Results table you will generate diagnostic information in worksheet “Diag” which you can work down to see what the macro does at every step.

The diagram below might help.  For this diagram, I set `RowRsltArrMax= 5` and created a 6 row KeyValue table.    After sorting, the KeyValue table is loaded to an array for easy access:

```
Index  Key     Value
1      AB   -205,082
2      AF    -74,308
3      AC    293,704
4      AE    651,560
5      AA    761,311
6      AD    852,254
```

The Pending array has two columns: `Expn` and `Diff`.  `Expn` contains strings that represent a combination while `Diff` contains the difference between the total value of the combination and the Target.  The Pending array is seeded with one row per positive value from the KeyValue table.  The left column of the diagram below represents the seeds.  The top row of each box contains a combination, the second row contains the total value of that combination and the third contains shows that total value as Target minus the total value.

[image: Diagram showing development of pending combination]

The Pending array is only seeded with positive values; this is one of three restrictions that ensure the same combination cannot be generated more than once.  This particular restriction means that no combination containing only negative values can be generated.  This will only be issue if the target value is negative or a low positive value.  This technique could be extended to allow for such target values but I assume this is not necessary.

The routine loops until the Pending array is empty.  Each repeat removes the bottom row of the Pending table as a possibly satisfactory combination and then adds rows to the Pending table for any possibly better combination it can generate from the one just removed.

Consider the bottom left box in the diagram.  Key AD has a value of 852,254 which is 198,813 more than the target.  We can hope this is not the best combination to be found but it will be placed in the Results array until something better is found.

Since this combination has a total above the target, only adding negative values could lead to a better combination.  Since the combination does not contain any negative values, one combination is created and added to the Pending array for each negative value.  These new combinations are shown in the bottom right of the diagram.

Both of these new combinations will in turn be taken as the second and third entry in the Result array.  However, never of these combinations can be the basis for a better combination.

AB+AD has a total 6,269 below the target so we would have to add positive values get a better combination.  However, this combination already contains AD which is the lowest positive value in the KeyValue table.  The second restriction to ensure only one copy of each combination is that only positive values below any existing positive values can be added.  The combination AB+AA+AD will be created later by adding AD to AB+AA.

AF+AD has a total 124,505 above the target so we would have to add negative values get a better combination.  However, this combination already contains AF which is the lowest negative value in the KeyValue table.  The third restriction to ensure only one copy of each combination is that only negative values below any existing negative values can be added.

The next combination to be taken as a possible result is AA.  The diagram shows that AF+AA and AB+AA will be generated from it.  No further combination can be generated from AF+AA but AB+AA+AD can be generated from AB+AA.  No further combination can be generated from AB+AA+AD.

If you want to explore the combinations generated from AE and AC, create a KeyValue table to match mine and run the macro with the diagnostic code active.

I cannot devise a technique that will examine fewer combinations than this one.  I have more-or-less convinced myself that potentially good combinations are not ignored.  Since it finds so many on-target combinations with larger sets, it may not matter if a few are overlooked.

The secret of any such technique is to correctly identify blind alleys at the earliest possible moment.  I have identified two.  Perhaps you can identify one that is better than either of mine.  Good luck.

I have have had to post the code for Approach 3 separately because of the character limit on the size of an answer.

Comment: I couldn´t have imagined an answer like yours when I posted this question; clearly beyond expectations. 
You´re giving a class more than an answer here. 
Wish there was a "promote answer" here. 
MANY THANKS!

Comment: @Luis You need to accept the answer by clicking the outline arrow to move it to the top. For my original answer, I posted a routine I had coded long ago. As the scale of your requirement became clearer, I doubt I would have bothered if Nuclearman had not linked to an approach I decided to explore.